# What is the scope of variable within a @Model Java class?

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I'm running into a weird issue. I call ProcessInfo which runs some logic and set continueRegistration to true.  On my form I have a  that calls the Register method.  Now the ProcessInfo is always ran before Register  so this should set continueRegistration to true which it does, but when the Register method is called continueRegistration shows up as false.   Any idea why it is not being set?

I put a print statement in the mutator and it shows that its is being set to true.

```
@Model
public class LoginController implements Serializable{
private boolean continueRegistration;

public void ProcessInfo(){
... do something
    setContinueRegistration(true)
}

public void Register(){
   if(getContinueRegistration()){
     ...continue flow
   }
}

public boolean getContinueRegistration() {  
        return continueRegistration;
}

public void setContinueRegistration(boolean continueRegistration) {
    System.out.println("Set continueRegistration: "+continueRegistration);
    this.continueRegistration = continueRegistration;
}
```

Comment: From which package comes the `@Model` annotation?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza java.enterprise.inject.Model

Comment: Are you calling this from different threads?  In some cases you need to add 'volatile' to ensure that the threads see each other's changes.

Comment: @AgilePro No I'm not but I will try volatile to see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you are calling `ProcessInfo` and then `Register` in separate requests. This obviously won't work because `@Model` is a stereotype which has `@RequestScoped` so that means this bean will be always recreated on every request. See the source

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
@Stereotype
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Model {}
```

So if your registration is a multistep process then I would suggest you to use `@ConversationalScoped` which will survive multiple requests and you can control all steps you need to finish the registration. Some basic tutorial [here](http://blog.goyello.com/2011/06/08/jee6-cdi-and-conversation-scope/).

P.S. Java convention says that you should use first letter in lowercase for naming Java methods, so change for instance `processInfo()`